# How to lock MATLAB files keeping them executable

Tags: matlab, locking, code-security

**How to lock MATLAB files keeping them executable.**

I am writing code to create GUI where third party should run the .fig file but should be unable to read the code written. Main GUI editor file contains user defined functions also, where they should be locked too with capability of execution. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can p-code your MATLAB functions:
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/protect-your-source-code.html

Comment: Also, I believe that if you generate an executable from your GUI with the MATLAB Compiler, the source code is also obfuscated.